# Why does __prepare__ take name and bases as parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I'm in the process of migrating from 2.7 to 3.x and I'm trying to understand the `__prepare__` method for metaclasses introduced in [PEP3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/).

In most of the examples I've seen, implementations of this method ignore the parameters (`name`, `bases`, and `**kwargs`) simply returns a custom dictionary that does something interesting to the namespace provided to the `__new__` and `__init__` methods for the metaclass. Even the [example in PEP3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/#id12) does nothing with the parameters.

I don't doubt that there is some good reason for the signature of `__prepare__` but I haven't seen the use case.

What are some good examples that demonstrate the rational for making the signature of `__prepare__` take these parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a *good* rationale, but those arguments are also passed to the `__new__` and `__init__` methods, so it may just be a case of passing the arguments to `__prepare__` too since they're available to the interpreter and might theoretically be useful (even if there isn't an immediate need for them).

Answer (score 2):

__prepare__ will create a namespace for the class like you said, so we can do some logic inside of it like this:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, klass_name, bases):
        namespace = {'s': 'my string',
                     'description': 'N/A'}
        if klass_name.endswith('Base'):
            namespace.update({'description': 'base class'})

        return namespace

class KlassBase(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class SubKlass(KlassBase):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)

print(KlassBase(5).s)
print(KlassBase(5).description)
print(SubKlass(5).s)
print(SubKlass(5).description)
```

And you got:

```
my string
base class
my string
N/A
```

The reason why we don't do it, because same things could be done in other part of the meta class like : __new__, __init__, or be overrided by the latter. So most of time, we won't do it in __prepare__

The following is an image of the class creation work-flow, which is much more clearer:

[image]

[sorry I cannot find the original source of this pic]

Comment: [the diagram is from Ionel's blog post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/)

Answer (score 0):

When you look at `__prepare__`, and the state of Python class creation mechanism at the time, it is pretty much clear that what was really needed was a mechanism to enable attribute order preservation.

This way, one would be able to create classes that would describe data records with ordered fields, which is pretty much what humans would expect when describing a record. (Try to imagine a form that each time it is rendered, it shuffles the field ordes, so half the time you will be filling in the country you live in before the country).

Instead of a fixed mechanism to just enable the class body namespace to be an collections.OrderedDict, they came up with `__prepare__` which enables this easily, with a single line returning a new OrderedDict instance.

But `__prepare__` can have so many uses and abuses, that I think no one really thought of all the possibilities. The parameters ou mentioned are avaliable at the time it is called, and since it exists, there is no reason whatsoever for they not to be passed to the function. Why to cripple one of knowing the class' name inside the `__prepare__` function?

So, it is just a powerful and flexible mechanism put in place, and not necessarily all possible use cases were thought of when making it. The "Ordered Attributes" thing n the other hand is so important that it became the default for Python 3.6, with PEP 520, even without any custom metaclass declaration.

`__prepare__` receivog bases, for example, would allow one to pre-populate the namespace with certain objects that would be found in the superclass namespaces, overriding the inheritance attribute access, for example.
Or it could simply check the class name against a pre-existing registry, and either raise or pre-populate stuff from there.

One super-easy usage would be to pre-populate  `__name__` for example, so that class attributes could make use of it:

```
import collections

class M(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases):
        ns = collections.OrderedDict()
        ns["__name__"] = name

class T(metaclass=M):
    __table__ = f"_{__name__.lower()}"
```

## trivia

Due to the way functions work as methods in Python 3, one interesting related thing that is not documented anywhere is that *if `__prepare__` is not explicitly decorated to be a `classmethod`, it works as a `staticmethod`*, and the target class name is passed directly in the first parameter to it.